# Only one image appeared in listview

Tags: asp.net

I have a generic handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg,png,jpg,gif";
        int newsId = int.Parse(context.Session["newsId"].ToString());
        int FK_UnitId = int.Parse(context.Session["UserData"].ToString());
        Managers.Photo p = new Managers.Photo();
        string dirPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("ThePath").First() + "/" + "NewsImages" + "/" + "UnitNum" + FK_UnitId.ToString() + "_" + "NewsNum" + newsId.ToString() + "/";
        string dirPathForTextFiles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("ThePath").First() + "/" + "NewsTextFiles" + "/" + "UnitNum" + FK_UnitId.ToString() + "_" + "NewsNum" + newsId + "/";
        DataTable dt = p.GetAllPhotos(newsId);
        List<string> l = new List<string>(dt.Rows.Count);
        byte[] b = null;
        FileStream f;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                l.Add(dirPath + dt.Rows[i]["photoName"].ToString());
                f = new FileStream(l[i].ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                b = new byte[f.Length];
                f.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                context.ClearError();
                f = null;
                b = null;

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
           string message =  e.Message;
        }


    }
```

and a list view on my page: the .cs file contains

```
Session.Add("newsId", newsId);  
string dirPath =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("ThePath").First() + "/" + "NewsImages" + "/" + "UnitNum" + FK_UnitId.ToString() + "_" + "NewsNum" + newsId + "/";  
string dirPathForTextFiles =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("ThePath").First() + "/" + "NewsTextFiles" + "/" + "UnitNum" + FK_UnitId.ToString() + "_" + "NewsNum" + newsId + "/";  
DataTable dt = p.GetAllPhotos(int.Parse(newsId));  
List<string> l = new List<string>(dt.Rows.Count);  
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)  
{  
    l.Add(dirPath + dt.Rows[i]["photoName"].ToString());  
}  
lv_showImages.DataSource = l;  
lv_showImages.DataBind();
```

my source

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv_showImages" GroupItemCount="4" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Image ID="img_newsImage" Height="100px" Width="100px" runat="server ImageUrl ='<%# "RetreiveImage.ashx" %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>  
</asp:ListView>`
```

Now my problem:

When the list has more than one path to set of images, only the first image has appeared and repeated, although I debug my handler and I find that length of b the byte array differs in the loop and this means that it is supposed to write different images rather than repeat the first image by the number of images, I don't know why the first image only appeared.

Comment: Have you used the <asp:Repeater> instead??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can return multiple images in a single request. I'm guessing that you are writing the contents of all of your images to the response but the browser only reads up to the end of the first image. You will have to change your handler to accept an image identifier parameter and return only that image.

Comment: but i wanna to return multiple images so i can delete,manage what i want,
when i debug the handler I'm sure that the size of array differs each time and so i conclude that it writes all the images but i don't know why only the first image appear and it appears several times(the number of images)

Comment: i do what u suggest , and i use paging to move among images ,it works ,thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy your code wrong or did you forget to close the  tag in your aspx page?  If it is not closed (and compiled), that could be your reason for not seeing multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a fairly similar problem.

I *think* it might be that you are using a `List<string>` instead of a `List<T>` which contains an object that holds a string property: `string imagePath { get; set; }`.

For some reason the DataBind has trouble iterating over string declarations and only iterates over object properties.

Comment: In my project I'm dumping the List altogether and using individual string properties for up to 4 elements. I don't think ASP is so good with nested Lists. Sorry it didn't work :(